# Update ... from optimization. Postgres 9.1

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, temp-tables

I have two huge tables:

```
tbl_a
id(int), cnt(int default:0)

tbl_b
id(int), a_id(int)
```

I neet to count all rows with the same a_id in tbl_b and put that value into tbl_a.

Here I found the way:

```
update tbl_a
set cnt = tb.c
from (select count(*) c,a_id from tbl_b group by a_id) tb
where tb.a_id = tbl_a.id
```

But that query works for about **8s** per 1000 rows. It's not acceptable, cause I have about 6M ones.

Tried to create temp table

```
... AS (select count(*),a_id from tbl_b group by a_id)
```

and even added b-tree index, but nothing changes.

Can that perform faster on the same hardware?

UPD1:

```
"Update on tbl_a  (cost=0.00..343357.80 rows=40000 width=459)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..343357.80 rows=40000 width=459)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on tbl_b_temp  (cost=0.00..617.00 rows=40000 width=18)"
"        ->  Index Scan using tbl_a_pkey on tbl_a  (cost=0.00..8.55 rows=1 width=445)"
"              Index Cond: (id = tbl_b_temp.a_id)"
```

rows=40000 because i created smaller temp table.

Query:

```
create temporary table tbl_b_temp as 
select count(*) as c, a_id from tbl_b group by a_id order by a_id limit 40000;

CREATE INDEX a_id_ind on tbl_b using btree (a_id);
```

Comment: Please post the execution plan and the index definitions for all indexes on the tables. You also might want to read this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: The column alias for `tb.c` is missing in the update query you presented. I assume that's just a typo. Also: for questions about optimization you *must* provide your version of Postgres.

Comment: I assume that's just a typo// yes. count(*) as c in first query.
Postgres 9.1

Comment: The execution plan you posted doesn't seem to correspond to any of the queries you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with a (big) temporary table, be sure to run `ANALYZE` after creating or changing it, since autovacuum does not cover temporary tables. This may improve the query plan Postgres comes up with.

[Quoting the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/routine-vacuuming.html)

> Temporary tables cannot be accessed by autovacuum. Therefore,
>   appropriate vacuum and analyze operations should be performed via
>   session SQL commands.

Comment: Yep. But it* reduced time for about twice. I need at least 10 times or more.

*I tried to create normal table, not temp.

Comment: @knes: A temp table is good for the job. Just run `ANALYZE tbl_b_temp` after filling it.